# No route matches [GET] "/... (problema al intentar acceder a un enlace)

Tags: html5, ruby-on-rails

Buen dia. Soy nuevo usando Ruby on rails, debo hacer algo similar al diseño de un Ecommerce para un trabajo de la universidad. Sucede que tengo los archivos HTML, y pensaba que solo con pasarlos al IDE y llamarlos entre ellos al estar en la misma carpeta funcionariaa, pero al ir al navegador y abrir el index si intento usar un hipervínculo no me direcciona al archivo y me muestra algo como
No route matches [GET] "/ecommerce/(nombre del archivo). ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?, he pasado unas cuantas horas tratando de solucionarlo pero no encontrado una que lo solucione del todo.
[image: aca podemos ver tanto la etiqueta con el vinculo del documento al que queremos ir y a la izquierda el nombre de los archivos y su tipo de extension, no se si tenga que ver que solo sean .HTML o deben ser .HTML.ERB]
[image: ahí estoy en el navegador y trato de ir ala pagina de contactos]
[image: aca podemos ver el tipo de error que genra al intentar dirigirnos a la pagina contactos.HTML]
[image: acá está el archivo de rutas, si abro el archivo directamente en el navegador(el archivo about) se abre, pero si intento accederlo desde el link no funciona]
[image: vi que acá también se debían hacer modificaciones]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu archivo de rutas? por el error al parecer en tu archivo de rutas no has definido las peticiones para poder renderizar tus templates

Comment: La ruta del archivo se encuentra en config/routes.rb

Comment: vale ya agregue la imagen, la verdad sigo en lo mismo, se que seguro es algo muy sencillo de solucionar pero realmente tengo muy poco usando Ruby on rails.

Comment: Te recomiendo dar el recorrido de como preguntar, todo archivo que añadas a tu pregunta debe ir como código y no como captura de pantalla, de lo contrario tu pregunta corre el riesgo de ser cerrada

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo de rutas estas llamando funciones del controlador  e**commerce_controller.rb** las funciones index y about se encuentran vacias, en tu archivo de rutas le indicas que a la peticion get a donde quieres que te redireccione,
por ejemplo en **routes.rb**

```
get 'ecommerce/index'
```

donde el primer parámetro es el controlador y el segundo la función, hay una manera de redireccionar a archivos sin pasar por el controlador:

```
get "/about" => redirect("ruta del archivo erb")
```

pero no es la mejor manera de renderizar templates, te recomiendo leer mas sobre la arquitectura de MVC, para entender rails debes tener los principios básicos de MVC
espero poder entenderme
Saludos